# ASP.NET MVC 4 EF Update operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let's say I have a table with 30 fields and I want to display(Edit.cshtml) 2 fields (GET) and update(public ActionResutl Edit(items, items)) only 4 fields

Edit.cshtml : RegNo = 1002 | Value = 50

ItemsController :

```
        public ActionResult Edit(items items)
        {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
              db.items.Attach(items);
              items.DateAdd = DateTime.Now;
              items.Status = 2;
              db.SaveChanges();
           }
        }
```

**Q:** How can I update only this 4 fields of 30 ?

Do I have to add 26 Html.HiddenFor() helpers ?
|| Make a small class with 4 fields and try update that (*TryUpdateModel, ApplyCurrentValues*) ?

EDIT : I'm updateing only one row.

SQL :

```
UPDATE dbo.items SET Status = 2, RegNo = items.RegNo WHERE id = items.id -- i don't care about the other fields
```

Comment: Very confusing way to ask it :O.

You can update individual rows by db.items.Single(itemID => itemID.ID == items.ID).<the Field you need to update> = <value> ;

Comment: From memory, since its a while ago I used .NET. EF is smart enough to generate an update statement with only 2 SET <col> = <value> if you only change 2 values. I believe EF heavily uses the INotifyPropertyChanged interface(not sure if I spelled that correctly) Which probably explains how it understands how many fields it needs to update. Other then that. Just persist the changes and it should generate the right query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I would have done in the actionresult method in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Items items)
{
db.Items.Single(ItemID => ItemID.ID == items.ID).<First Column to update> = <the value needed>;
db.Items.Single(ItemID => ItemID.ID == items.ID).<Second Column to update> = <the value needed>;
db.Items.Single(ItemID => ItemID.ID == items.ID).<Third Column to update> = <the value needed>;
db.Items.Single(ItemID => ItemID.ID == items.ID).<Fourth Column to update> = <the value needed>;
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

So lets go on example

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Items items)
{
db.Items.Single(ItemID => ItemID.ID == items.ID).Status = 2;
db.Items.Single(ItemID => ItemID.ID == items.ID).Barcode = Abc12345;
db.Items.Single(ItemID => ItemID.ID == items.ID).RegNo = 1002;
db.Items.Single(ItemID => ItemID.ID == items.ID).Manufacturer = Tomato Soup Inc;
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Comment: This way you only update the fields you need to update, and you do not need to do every single field in your table

Comment: It looks for the single record where the every row in the model's ID (in this example) is equal to those in the database table. It takes the single method, you can assign a value to it, then call SaveChanges(); on your db to submit your values

Comment: I have 2 fields that are coming from the View(RegNo, Value) and 2 fields that are set programmatically (DateAdd, Status)

Comment: Having a hard thinking session now :?

Comment: What I see from your method is that it is assumed that an Items model is passed into your HttpPost method. Is this correct?

Comment: It really seems to me that you are making things way too complicated for yourself :|

Answer (score 2):

You need to include all the fields or look up the object in the post back and only changes the fields of interest.

Comment: No.  But if you look at the object posted back, the data isn't there.  That's why you need to look up the object again.

Comment: The only data there is the ID and the 2 fields from my View. So I have to make a select again for the other 27 fields ?

Comment: Yes, that's the only other way I know of to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Only Single fields update in MVC4 EF & This Code is Correct Working.

```
db.Booking_transactions.Single(b => b.BookingId == booking_transaction.BookingId ).booking_status = 2;
```